# Leiningen fails to work with newly generated project

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

I have a problem running Leiningen on Windows (in both Cygwin and CMD).

When at first I generated project:

```
$ lein new app leintest
Generating a project called leintest based on the 'app' template.
```

and then I tried to run it:

```
$ cd leintest/
$ lein run
$
```

it shown no result. `-main` function has `println`:

```
$ cat src/leintest/core.clj
(ns leintest.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

and it is pointed by `project.clj`:

```
$ cat project.clj
(defproject leintest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot leintest.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

So basically I am unable to `run` template project. What is more I am also unable to build `uberjar`:

```
$ lein uberjar
Warning: The Main-Class specified does not exist within the jar. It may not be executable as expected. A gen-class directive may be missing in the namespace which contains the main method.
Created E:\Workspaces\leintest\target\uberjar\leintest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created E:\Workspaces\leintest\target\uberjar\leintest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

As I understand it doesn't even find main class. When I tried to debug that with `repl` I learned that `REPL server launch timed out.`.

My version of Leningen is `Leiningen 2.4.3 on Java 1.7.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`. I see the same behavior whether I use `lein` script (Cygwin) or `lein.bat` (CMD).

What can I do to figure out where things break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by a `JAVA_PATH` system variable.

I have 2 Java installations - standard one and portable one. Standard one added itself to `PATH` variable so that `java` would execute `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe`.

In Cygwin I added `JAVA_PATH` pointing to the portable installation and added its directory to the path (`SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_PATH%\bin`). However since that directory occurred after the one added by nonportable installation it was ignored. Mismatch between `JAVA_PATH` variable and directory in `PATH` made `lein` script call fail. Meanwhile in CMD I had no `JAVA_PATH` set at all.

When I made sure that `JAVA_PATH` is set correctly and it is added to the `PATH` before the standard installation (`SET PATH=%JAVA_PATH%\bin;PATH`) everything started to work.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, I had this same problem but my environmental variables were set correctly.  In my case, unlike the questioner, I had failed to add the :gen-class directive in a namespace declaration in the file with the main method.  It was resolved by appending the second line below to the namespace declaration:

```
(ns async-test.core
  (:gen-class :main true)
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as async]))
```